# JsonParseException with jsonResponse

Tags: json, jsp, jackson

Not able to parse the json I get from my service. I'm using Jackson API to parse the json. I'm getting JsonParseException:

```
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('>' (code 62)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
```

JSON response:

```
 { "errors":[  ], 
 "id":"1",  
 "employee":{ "firstName":"bishop<!--\"><script src=//xss.bf.mg></script>-->", 
           "lastName":"fox\"><script src=//xss.bf.mg></script>"
 }
 }
```

My java code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        MyEmployee emp = 
objectMapper.readValue(jsonResponse, MyEmployee.class);
```

If I get a valid json from the service, i'm able to deserialize the json successfully. I also used the JsonStringEncoder to encode the json, but still getting JsonMappingException.

```
  jsonResponse = String.valueOf(JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString(jsonResponse));
```

Please help.

Comment: What Jackson version are you using?

Comment: jackson version  2.5.3

Comment: What is the type of `jsonResponse` variable ? Is it a String ?

Comment: yes jsonResponse is a string

Comment: if i replace \" in the jsonResponse, i'm not getting any exception but it then fails when i show these values on the UI, as the UI takes it as html tags: 
      <script></script>. I need to show it as it is in the table in which i render the employee list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a `String` literal to jackson to deserialize you'll have to escape the backslash that escapes the double quote within the value as well as the double quote. E.g. this code works fine:

```
String jsonResponse = " { \"errors\":[ ], \n" +
        " \"id\":\"1\",  \n" +
        " \"employee\":{ \"firstName\":\"bishop<!--\\\"><script src=//xss.bf.mg></script>-->\", \n" +
        "           \"lastName\":\"fox\\\"><script src=//xss.bf.mg></script>\"\n" +
        " }\n" +
        " }";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyEmployee emp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonResponse, MyEmployee.class);
```

Note that there is a total of 3 backslashes before each double quote within a value in json. E.g the value for `firstName` withing the `String` that you pass to `readValue` is written as:

```
\"bishop<!--\\\"><script src=//xss.bf.mg></script>-->\"
```

That's :

1. a backslash to escape the double quote within the `String` literal.
2. a backslash to escape the double quote within a string in a json field.
3. another backslash to escape the latter backslash within the `String` literal.

Comment: Thanks..it works,,I found another way of doing this..I created a custom JsonDeserializer and that solved my issue. :)